# Javaで書いたDiscordのbotをIBM Cloud上で動かしたいが、やり方がわからない

Tags: java, windows, ibm-cloud

チャットツールのひとつであるDiscordというアプリで、Javaを使ってbotを制作しました。これをIBM Cloudで動かしたいのですが、ローカルに保存してあるコードをどのようにIBM Cloud上で動かすのかがわかりません。使用しているOSはWindows10です。

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/apps/create-deploy-cli.html#byoc
このサイトの「デプロイメントおよびクラウド対応アセットの生成」という項目の指示を参考にして、WindowsPowerShellで操作を進めました。それの③番の手順まで進めたところ、画面に「言語を設定してください」というような指示が出たので、この画面に沿ってnode.js(サンプルコードの言語)からjavaに変更したところ、上記のサイトと画面がずれ、どうすればいいのかわからなくなってしまいました。

最終的に「このアプリケーションは既にデプロイメント可能です。」との表示が出たのですが、これはnode-helloworldというサンプルコードが正常に動いているということだと考えています。自分のリソースリストを確認しても、動いているのはnode-helloworldでした。これを自分のローカルに保存してある、DiscordBotのコードに置き換えたいのですがどうしたらよろしいでしょうか。

状況説明がうまくできず、拙く冗長な質問になってしまい申し訳ありませんがなにとぞ回答をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ちょっと違うかもしれませんがこれとか、[IBM-Cloud/java-helloworld](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/java-helloworld) あるいはもしかしたら、[Deploying a Java Discord Bot jar on Heroku](https://medium.com/@nastyworldgamer/deploying-a-java-discord-bot-jar-on-heroku-32020474ffcd) と [Herokuでbotを運用する時代は終わった。これからはIBM Bluemixを使って無料で運用する](https://qiita.com/akameco/items/39a55635ceb0ba185b7f) の組み合わせで考えられるのでは？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。また、返信が遅くなってしまい大変申し訳ございません。

いただいたURLすべて拝見しましたが、ピンポイントで私の問題を解決するものとはなりえませんでした。私の能力の低さが原因ではあるのだと思いますが、自力で解決することはできませんでした。

IBM Cloudに関しては、一度アプリケーションを停止・削除してもう一度やり直してみようと思います。